# Randomize Keyword Links

Tags: javascript, random, keyboard

I'm currently looking for a method to display five keywords/links at a time from a total of about 50 at random. So for example, a function to grab a keyword and the links to go with them at random, and have them display in a webpage according to what I prefer with CSS.

It sounds simple enough but I just can't seem to find the answer I'm looking for. Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like that?

```
function getRandomLinks(count,links){
    var randomlinks = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < count; i++){
        randomlinks.push(links.splice(Math.floor(Math.random()*links.length),1)[0]);
    }
    return randomlinks;
}
console.log(getRandomLinks(2,["link1","link2","link3","link4"]));
```

Comment: How would I go about having using that code to display only five of the keywords instead of mixing up all 50?